# Array value from variable

Tags: php, arrays

Could somebody explaind me ***why array count is not 2

```
$value = '"305", "112", ';
//remove last comma and space
echo $value = rtrim($value, ', ');
echo '<br>';

$value = array($value);

echo $array_length = count($value); //***
```

Comment: why wouldn't it be? you only add one element to it? o.O

Comment: Also - `print_r($value);`

Comment: Perhaps you wanted [`str_getcsv($value)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)?

Comment: $value = array("305", "112"); so you will have two data in the array

Comment: @treyBake I have this value in mysql column $value = '"305", "112", '; and I think that this is 2 elements, is possible make it two, why I said is two because if I pass it here $value = array($value); is two elements

Comment: but it's just one string, you don't explode on any delimiters to turn it into array, or you don't as NigelRen suggests, use `str_getcsv()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `explode()` to get it.

```
$value = '"305", "112", ';
//remove last comma and space
echo $value = rtrim($value, ', ');
echo '<br>';

$value = explode(',',$value);

echo $array_length = count($value);
```

Comment: Note you'll have two string values that contain double quotes surrounding each number in your array.

Answer (score 2):

You should use explode function to get array like the following code :

```
$value = '"305", "112"'; 
        $value = rtrim($value, ', ');
        echo '<br>';
        $value = explode(',',$value); 
        echo $array_length = count($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this if you want to create an array from that these type of strings and do array count.

```
$arr = array_filter(array_map('trim', str_getcsv($value)));
print_r($arr);
echo count($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating an array with `array($value)`, the entire value of `$value` counted as a single element of an array. Thats why you are getting `count($value)` not equal to 2.